# Select Sub menu

Tags: jquery, menu

I using of [selectable](http://css.flepstudio.org/demo/selectable/) for choice list.

```
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li> 
<li>item 3  
    <ul>        
        <li>item 3-1</li>       
        <li>item 3-2            
            <ul>                
                <li>item 3-2-1</li>
                <li>item 3-2-2</li>             
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</li>
```

if I choose `<li>` item 1,2 or 3 it is true but when I choose subset (for example: : item 3-2-1) eligitur selected main item (example : 3 item)

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: so what happened to you after then? Is your system get stucked so you left the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is going on first child's level. i think you must using nested loops for each level of child items or you can use $(this).html() method for each item by click like this:

HTML:

```
<li class="item">item 1</li>
<li class="item">item 2</li> 
<li class="item">item 3  
    <ul>        
        <li class="item">item 3-1</li>       
        <li class="item">item 3-2            
            <ul>                
                <li class="item">item 3-2-1</li>
                <li class="item">item 3-2-2</li>             
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</li>
```

JS:

```
$(".item").click(function() 
{
      item = $(this).html();
      checkSelection(item);
});

function checkSelection(item)
{
      alert("You chose " + item);
}
```